# how to set Web Grid visible false if list is empty using Razor

Tags: razor

In Razor I have bind the Web Grid using ADO.NET List. Then I need to set Web Grid  visible false if Empty List. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Simply test the model object for null value. See below working code:

```
@{
        if(Model != null)
        {

            var grid = new WebGrid(Model.ToList),canPage:true, rowsPerPage:    15,
            selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
            <div id="gridContent">
                @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                        headerStyle: "blue-gradient",
                        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                        selectedRowStyle: "select",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                        //grid.Column(null,null, format: @<input type="hidden" name="IDHidden" value="@item.EventID"/>),
                        //grid.Column("", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Submit", new { CaseId = item.File_Number }) </text>),
                        grid.Column("File_Number", "File Number", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink(((string)item.File_Number), "Review", new { CaseId = item.File_Number }) </text>),
                        grid.Column("File_Name", "File Name"),
                        grid.Column("Attorney", "Attorney"),
                        grid.Column("Reviewer", "Reviewer"),
                        grid.Column("Department", "Department"),
                        grid.Column("Review_Status", "Review Status"),
                        grid.Column("Claim_Number", "Claim Number"),
                        grid.Column("Status", "Case Status")
                 )) 
            </div>
        }

    }  

  Test for nulls and then if true, simply don't render the WebGrid at all
```